# mysql udf error - can't install in ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, user-defined-functions

I have trouble installing the mysql udf (https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys).  Here's what I'm getting:

```
Compiling the MySQL UDF
gcc -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o /usr/lib/lib_mysqludf_sys.so
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccw6HRtN.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/tmp/ccw6HRtN.o: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [install] Error 1
ERROR: You need libmysqlclient development software installed 
to be able to compile this UDF, on Debian/Ubuntu just run:
apt-get install libmysqlclient15-dev
```

Any ideas? TIA

UPDATED:

I have already the `libmysqlclient15-dev` installed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to recompile with `-fPIC` flag. It obviously hints at it:

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccw6HRtN.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; ***recompile with -fPIC***

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, however I've just had this issue using Ubuntu 16.

I solved changing the Makefile in the following way, [as explained in a GitHub issue](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_sys/issues/1):

```
LIBDIR=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin

install:
        gcc -DMYSQL_DYNAMIC_PLUGIN -fPIC -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -I. -shared lib_mysqludf_sys.c -o $(LIBDIR)/lib_mysqludf_sys.so
```